# How to ship java development env to many workstations

Tags: java, docker, ide, devops

I'm looking for a method to ship java development environment for many (>50) workstations with win, linux or mac.
My end-user is a java course student.

For me development environment is:

- jdk (OpenJdk or HotSpot)
- build tool (gradle)
- ide (idea)
- db (PostgreSQL)
- docker

Docker is a must on a workstation. 
First idea was to create a docker image with all I need and push it to the hub.
Then to pull and run image on workstations.
But I don't know how to work with dockerized ide if it is possible.

Any ideas how to make such shipment with docker?

Or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: In a similar setting we decided on using Vagrant to create a pre-configured virtual machine. Inside, we used Docker where appropriate.

Comment: If you're teaching CS, you may be interested in https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/ (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter through here https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators)

Comment: @C-Otto what problems did you get with Vagrant if any?

Comment: Vagrant itself was OK, the issues were related with having a VM (performance, Windows users on Linux machines, being outside of your regular Eclipse installation, ...).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd be better of with a traditional VM. Build the VM image with all the tools you want, package it up, distribute to your students.

You could use something like Xvfb to give your Docker image a graphical environment, but imo trying to Dockerize all of these things is probably more trouble than it's worth if the main goal is easy distribution.